# Python logging inheritance in PIP installed packages

Tags: python, logging, module, pip, package

So I've spent some time reading up on logging in python, but cannot find a clean solution to this particular problem.

I have three separate packages-- two that stand alone and one that is a library used by both. I'm using pip and artifactory to manage that dependency. I've read that the convention for submodule inheriting is to instantiate the loggers using `logging.getLogger(__name__)`, which works great if it's inside the same package. But as soon as it's another package, the module name starts at the beginning again.

Is there a way to have my library package agnostically inherit the logger config from the package that is calling it?

I could configure the default root logger, but it's definitely bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have my library package agnostically inherit the logger config from the package that is calling it?

*NB : I assume you mean "inherit the logger instance" - configuration is a totally distinct matter - actually separating loggers instanciation and calls from logging configuration is one of the raison d'être of the logging module.*

And well, a logger is just another python object. You can pass it explicitely to all callables needed a logger but that's a bit cumbersome. The point is: why would you do such a thing anyway ? If you log something from your lib you certainly want it to be logged by your lib's own logger. As far as I'm concerned I wouldn't want a 3rd part lib to log anything under one of my own loggers.

If you perceive this as a problem chances are you're not using `logging` the right way. As I mentionned above, one of the points of the logging module is to totally separate logger's usage (instanciation and calls) from logging's config (setting up handlers, formatters, levels, propagation etc). **Library code is not supposed to do any configuration** - it only *uses* loggers. Configuring the logging is the application code responsability, and can range from merely configuring the root logger to print to `sys.stderr` to highly sophisticated configuration with different handlers / levels per sub-logger, dispatching to different outputs (syslog, emails, sentry etc) according to the level and/or sub-logger.

Comment: So the reason for my question is, I'd like to _use_ my app logger in my lib, but not pass down every time.

My configuration is happening in the app, but I haven't found a clean way for my lib to use the logger or have a child of that logger, in order to have the same handlers and filters apply to the lib logs depending on which app using it.

Comment: Then I confirm that you dont understand how the logging library separates logger usage from logging configuration. You do **not** have to "pass you app logger" to the lib, all you need is to properly configure logging in your app. Depending on your specific needs, you can either specifically configure your lib's logger (from your app's own logging config) or just configure the root logger and let it take care of everything (since all loggers are children of the root logger and - unless explicitely configured otherwise - loggers will propagate to their parent.

Comment: Oh and yes : "I could configure the default root logger, but it's definitely bad practice." => well, no it isn't. That's even why there's a root logger and propagation from children to their parents.

Comment: My current solution is defining the loggers as such:

`custom_root`

`custom_root.lib`

But since the custom_root name needs to be agreed upon by both apps using the lib, I have defined the custom_root name as a constant in the lib. 

What you are saying is, it's fine to define the root logger's config. But won't this affect the logging of 3rd party modules?

Comment: It's not "fine" to configure the root logger, it's actually what you _should_ do (in your app of course).  This of course mean that it will (by default) collect log calls from all modules (depending on the root logger's level and it's handler(s) level(s)). THEN you can add per-package specific config if you want more (or less) verbose output, different handlers, preventing propagation to the root logger etc. And this is also why library code should NOT  configure logging at all - it's the app's responsability, period.

Comment: So it sounds like I understood: 1. logs propagate from children to parent, 2. loggers should not get configured in the library. Sorry if I was being unclear. I was wrong about configuring the root to be bad practice because I read that on a SO answer. Thanks for correcting that.

Comment: "logs propagate from children to parent" => unless you specifically configure the logger otherwise (setting `propagate = False`). And I'd appreciate if you could send me a link to this SO answer.